# jquery display current element on hover

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So I use this code to display depth 3 elements in menu (wordpress):

```
var hoverTimeout;  

    $( "span.sub2 li.menu-item-has-children" ).hover(function(){
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {$('ul .sub2 li .sub-menu .sub2').css("display", "block");}, 500);
    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
        $('ul .sub2 li .sub-menu .sub2').css("display", "none");
    });


    $( "span.sub2 li.menu-item-has-children" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $('ul .sub2 li .sub-menu .sub2').css("display", "none");
    });
```

Problem is that when I hover on one element with sub-menu, all elements with sub-menus get displayed.

Question is:

**How to display only one sub menu that I'm hovering my mouse at the moment?**

sorry for tags, couldn't add "jquery"

edit:

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu" class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation" class=""><li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-177"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/">Strona główna</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/o-firmie/">O firmie</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-19"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/">Oferta</a><ul class="sub-menu"><span class="sub2">  <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/sprzedaz-plynow-chlodniczych-i-wody-demineralizowanej/">Sprzedaż płynów chłodniczych i wody demineralizowanej</a><ul class="sub-menu"><span class="sub2">       <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-435"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/producent-wody-demineralizowanej/">Producent wody demineralizowanej</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-436"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/plyny-instalacji-przemyslowych/">Płyny do instalacji przemysłowych i CO</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-437" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-437"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/inhibitory-korozji/">Inhibitory korozji</a></li>
</ul></span></li>
    <li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-119"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/analizy-badania-czystosci-i-stopnia-zuzycia-plynow-chlodniczych/">Analizy, badania czystości i stopnia zużycia płynów chłodniczych</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-120"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/napelnianie-i-oproznianie-instalacji-chlodniczych/">Napełnianie i opróżnianie instalacji chłodniczych</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/plukanie-chemiczne-czyszczenie-lub-trawienie-urzadzen-i-ciagow-technologicznych/">Płukanie, chemiczne czyszczenie lub trawienie urządzeń i ciągów technologicznych</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/oferta/plyny-niezamarzajace-do-domkow-letniskowych/">Płyny niezamarzające do domków letniskowych</a></li>
</ul></span></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://ekochem-tech.pl/kontakt/">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML in your question please?

Comment: I've just added it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a selector like `span li.menu-item` will apply to every `li.menu-item` within the `span` regardless of depth (it's a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)). You should use [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to only target the immediate children, like this `span > li.menu-item`.

*Edit: updated to include delay as per question.*
Without the delay you could do this entirely in CSS. For the delay to work though, it's most likely easier to use JavaScript to add a class that indicates when the user has been hovering for long enough to trigger the display and keep how that should look in your CSS.

```js
var timeout;

$('.menu-item').hover(function() {

  var element = $(this);

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    element.addClass('hovering');
  }, 200);

}, function() {

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $(this).removeClass('hovering');

});
```

```css
li.menu-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

li.menu-item.hovering > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-navigation">
  <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    Sub menu
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        Sub-sub menu
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>2 Level Nested</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ur way it works almost perfect, I need to use jquery because I need some delay on hover like 2 sec so you won't open some sub menu by mistake

Comment: Sure, in that case the same selector structure but in your jQuery selectors  instead of your CSS should work.

Comment: I use now something like this var hoverTimeout;
 $( "li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul" ).css(function(){
  hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {$('li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul').css("display", "block");}, 1500);
 }, function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
  $('li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul').css("display", "none");
 });     but now delay doesn't works

Comment: Edited to include how you could handle the delay by combining CSS to control the styling and JS to control when the styles are applied.

Comment: Thanks! It works just perfect now, that will help me with fututure websites aswell :)